# How to run the SharePoint list every year for the same date?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

[image: sharepoint list]

[image: sharepoint design]

I need to run the same list every year for the same date could someone please

help me

Answer (score 1):

From your question its not clear but i guess you probably need to run the workflow once a year for a given list.

In such case you can use workflow action 'Add Time to Date'. This action let you add exact months, days, hours and mins even. To run the workflow once a year, just set the days to 365. That's it.

[image]

Comment: I need to run the SharePoint list every year for the same date, for example i have sharepoint list with the reminder date so it should send email reminder automatically on that date, what I need is  it should  send the same reminder next year for the same date

Comment: I am not sure what this line mean `run the SharePoint list every year` but what I conclude is, you need to run a reminder on a period. For ex. you may have SP List where you put all the reminders like `Pay Mobile Bill`, `Pay Electricity Bill`. Here the frequency will be 30 days (or 7 days for a weekly reminder, while 365 days annual reminder). You can use the same logic for annual events. To achieve this, create a list with following columns: `Name`, `Frequency`, `Notify to`, and `Notification body`. Create a list item level workflow and use the above logic by getting frequecny from list item.